# DOMDocument Remove div and it content by identifier with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, domdocument

Hi I wanna remove a line from a HTML file with PHP
like this:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="buttonid_4"><a href="#">Button 4</a></div>
    <div id="buttonid_3"><a href="#">Button 3</a></div>
    <div id="buttonid_2"><a href="#">Button 2</a></div>
    <div id="buttonid_1"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>
</div>
```

So, I wanna remove the buttonid_4, and it content. 
That it will be like this:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="buttonid_3"><a href="#">Button 3</a></div>
    <div id="buttonid_2"><a href="#">Button 2</a></div>
    <div id="buttonid_1"><a href="#">Button 1</a></div>
</div>
```

First I think it is easy, but I can't found the answer :|

I tried:
"as simple"

```
                    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
                    $dom->loadHTMLFile($The_Path_For_File);
                    $element = $dom->getElementById('buttonid_'. $Button_Id);
                    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
                    $dom->saveHTMLFile($The_Path_For_File);
```

I got

> Call to a member function removeChild() on a non-object

and everytime when I tried with GetElementById, so I continue with XPATH:

```
                    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

                    $nodeList = $xpath->query('//div[@id="buttonid'.$Button_Id.'"]');
                    foreach($nodeList as $element){
                        $dom->$element->removeChild($element);
                    }
                    $dom->saveHTMLFile($The_Path_For_File);
```

I didn't get error, the notepad requested the refresh for file, but no change 
Anyone know how to produce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `getElementById` requires a Document Type Declaration (DTD).
 [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

Notice your HTML fails validation `$dom->validate()`

Just add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to your HTML and it will work.

> For this function to work, you will need either to set some ID
>   attributes with DOMElement::setIdAttribute or a DTD which defines an
>   attribute to be of type ID. In the later case, **you will need to
>   validate your document with DOMDocument::validate** or
>   DOMDocument::$validateOnParse before using this function.